# Inline function in constructor in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm converting response to a Class like this:

```
private mapSingle(response: SingleResponse): CodeExample {
    var authorResponse = response.modular_content[response.item.elements.author.value as string];
    var author = new Author(authorResponse.system, authorResponse.elements.name.value, authorResponse.elements.image.value);
    return new CodeExample(
        response.item.system,
        response.item.elements.code.value,
        author,
        response.item.elements.versions.value as CodeExampleCategory[],
        response.item.elements.title.value,
        response.item.elements.versions.value as CodeExampleVersion[]
    );
}
```

Even though this works perfectly fine, I'm hoping there is a better way to do this so that I don't need to declare the **author** response before the constructor. Ideally I would like to put my own function in constructor and resolve this "inline". Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

From your coding style, my guess is that you have *not* had previous experiences with javascript before picking up typescript. If I'm wrong I apologize. The reason I say this is because developers from other languages have the ability to overload their constructors/methods by using different method signatures but in typescript/javascript, that is not the case.

> Ideally I would like to put my own function in constructor and resolve this "inline". Is this possible?

I apologize if this doesn't directly answer your question but my intuition tells me that you probably want to solve your by overloading your constructor. Since typescript/javascript, doesn't let you do this, there is another 'pattern'/'best practice' to make the constructor take in a [configuration object](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Allow_for_configuration_and_translation) instead of many parameters.

So to tie everything together, instead of having your constructors take in many arguments, your constructor should take in one configuration object. You can declare an `interface` with optional parameters for this options and then satisfy the interfaces with an object literal.

```
interface CodeExampleOptions {
    requiredParam: string,
    someOptionalParam?: string,
    authorResponse?: Author
}

class CodeExample {
    constructor(options: CodeExampleOptions) {
        // do something with options
        if (options.authorResponse !== undefined) {
            // do something with the authorResponse 
        }
    }
}

// now your method could look something like this.
private mapSingle(response: SingleResponse): CodeExample {
    return new CodeExample({
        // someOptions: 'some values',
        authorResponse: response.modular_content[response.item.elements.author.value as string],
        // someOtherOptions: 'some other values'
    });
}
```

This is how I address wanting to 'overload constructors' in typescript if that's what you were hoping to do.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the awesome response! My main goal was to be able to make the code cleaner/shorter by having functions inside object initialization so that I don't have to declare those outside or wrap them in a separate function. I'll try this approach, see how that works and will get back to this answer, Thanks again!